# matplotlib.pyplot picture is corrupted when the picture is too wide

Tags: python, matplotlib

A minimum working example is here:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_points = 1000
op_norms = range(1, num_points + 1)
op_names = ["name {}".format(p) for p in op_norms]
    
figwidth = 300
f = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(figwidth, 6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
for i, op_norm in enumerate(op_norms):
    plt.semilogy(i, op_norm, "o")

plt.xticks(np.arange(num_points), op_names, rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("wideplot_width_{}.png".format(figwidth))
plt.close()
```

When `figwidth=300`, everything is fine; see pic [figwidth=300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTeTE.png). However, when it is increased to `figwidth=400`, the plot is corrupted (boarder is not complete, x axis label not complete, dirty ink etc.); see pic [figwidth=400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cMCl.png). Any hint would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight')`?  Also note that the figsize is measured in inches. With a default of 100 dpi, `figwidth=400` makes your image `40_000` pixels wide. This seems very extreme.

Comment: Interesting - the first corruption appears at the right hand edge of the image with width 328; with that factor 100, this is where a signed 16-bit integer would have overflowed.

Comment: The critical value is indeed 328! Any hint on how to solve this issue? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks JohanC! I tried it and the dirty ink is gone, but the other issues like missing background and x-axis labels are still there.